# Is there a way to replace cloned model with the updated original model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clone

I am using [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) gem to create a copy of model and it's associations. When there is some change to the data in the original model, I want to keep that data in sync with the cloned model. I don't want to delete/re-create every time, as it generates new ID.

Is there a clean way to do this in ruby/rails?

Comment: why would you do that?! why keep a copy and then update it to the original?!

Comment: It's one of the business requirements. Think more like github model. You clone the repo, work on it, and then merge to main branch.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that you will have a good experience with this approach. how are you going to keep track of changes to the copy? will the original override the values every time?

your analogy to github does not make sense because changes in the parent are not reflected in the child. every change that i do in a fork are local to my fork. every change in the origin are local to the origin.

HOWEVER

you could use rails observers: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

callbacks: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

notifications: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html

to transparently monitor changes on whatever AR object you like.

Comment: I am not doing anything fancy.


My analogy to github is: Users will have a local workspace for their content, and they get to decide when to sync their local copy with master copy. Syncing will basically override the existing record.


I was able to get this working using regular rails features.

Just an FYI: Observers are deprecated in Rails 4.